# Undoing 'revert to checkpoint' on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I accidently pressed the "revert to checkpoint" option on Jupyter Notebok, and it reverted to a wrong version of my file. Now I can't seem to get back to what I had before I pressed the revert option, nor can I choose any of the more recent checkpoints I had made (it's just stuck on an older version of the file).

Is there anyway I can undo this and get my file back to its 'newest' version? It had autosaved before I did the revert button.
(Also, I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm using Python 3.0).